# how to show and hide text field from Observable object

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to show and hide a textfield in Content View from Observableobject

I have this

```
    class homeViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var defaultMessage = "What can I help you find ?"
        @Published var currentPlace = ""

        func ButtonPressed(){
    //
            if self.currentPlace == "" {
                   // tell user to type current place
                self.defaultMessage = "Please enter your place "
                

            } else {
                

            }


           }
    }
```

and the contentView

```
    struct ContentView: View {
        
        @ObservedObject var homeModel = homeViewModel()
        @State private var currentPlace: String = ""

       
             var body: some View {
             
             VStack{
             
              TextField("Please Enter your current place", text: $currentPlace).hidden()
              
              
                  Button(action: {
                                         withAnimation{
                                            self.homeModel.micButtonPressed()
                                    }
             
             }
          
          }
       }
```

if the current place is empty i want to show the textfield so that user can type their current place. How can I achieve this?

Comment: It seems like the @State currentPlace is duplicated. Why don't you use the one in your model?

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI you can easily show or hide views with if-conditions.

```
if homeModel.currentPlace == "" {
    TextField("Please Enter your current place", text: self.$homeModel.currentPlace)
}
```

Since currentPlace is @Published the view will automatically hide / show the TextField whenever the value changes.